# Team Foundation NuGet Packages Load

Tags: tfs, nuget

I'm not so familiar with ASP.NET, so I've been using a Web Forms project from Visual Studio that already implements login and membership control. This project has some NuGet packages installed and they work fine when you are working on your local machine.

I'm trying to work with a friend on this project, so we decided to use TFS, but when I upload the code to Team Foundation Server it does not work anymore. I got several errors that I did not have before uploading.  These are some of the errors:

> Error  20  The name 'BundleTable' does not exist in the current context    D:\Teste Moving Music\MovingMusic\MovingMusic\Global.asax.cs    17  42  MovingMusic
>
> Error  5   The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    D:\Teste Moving Music\MovingMusic\MovingMusic\App_Start\AuthConfig.cs   5   17  MovingMusic
>
> Error  22  The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\Teste Moving Music\MovingMusic\MovingMusic\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs 12  44  MovingMusic
>
> Error  19  The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) D:\Teste Moving Music\MovingMusic\MovingMusic\Global.asax.cs    5   18  MovingMusic
>
> Error  21  The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) D:\Teste Moving Music\MovingMusic\MovingMusic\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs 5   18  MovingMusic

I get almost 10 of these errors, but if I switch back to the same project on my local machine, it works with no error.

Can someone help me?  And sorry about my English - it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you need to right click on your solution and select "Enable NuGet Package Restore" as per the instructions at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

This will allow Visual Studio Team Services to download packages that are missing to avoid dependency errors.

Comment: I ran into the OP's problem myself on Visual Studio 2013 while moving a project from one TFS server to another: I toggled "Enable NuGet Package Restore", re-built the project, but the project still wouldn't build.  I ended up having to manually re-add some of the references to `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` (etc.) through the NuGet package manager console to get the project to build.